# Set viewport width to the scrollpane width

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Is there a way to fix the width of the viewport of a JScrollPane to the width of its owner (the JScrollPane). My goal is a JScrollPane with that its just possible to scroll down, but the width of the viewport is compressed / set to the size of the JScrollPane.

I tried to set the size of the Viewport manually, but it failed because I used a GridLayout to layout the components. I also tried GridBagLayout and set Constraints to the Viewport and its Components. I also diabled the horizontal scroller.

Im NOT familiar width Java FX.

Comment: Check out the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which can be customized by parameters to achieve different scrolling behaviour

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to implement the `Scrollable` interface for your panel. Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <code>ScrollableExample</code>.
 */
public class ScrollableExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ScrollableExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollablePanel();
        scrollPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            scrollPanel.add(new JLabel("It's a simple label to test whether scrolling works " + i));
        }
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test scrolling");
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(scrollPanel));
        frm.setSize(220, 200);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class ScrollablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 20;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            // no horizontal scroll bar
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```